# Распечатать имеющийся файл на хостинге на прямую

Tags: файлы, php, хостинг

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Есть файл `doc/docx/xls/xlsx` на хостинге, все там уже поправлено, нужно только распечатать. Тут начинается грусть, печаль, беда... в PHPWord/PHPExcel не нашел такого, в интернете пытаются разлагать эти файлы до xml и печатать.. Единственный способ - сохранение файла и печать

Подскажите, как распечатать имеющийся файл на хостинге используя PHP? Вот зашел я на нужную мне страницу на сайте, нажимаю печать - и пошла печать (выбор принтера и т.д...), но печать не страницы из инета а именно документа `doc/docx/xls/xlsx`

Comment: скачать то ее придется. Браузеры ещё не настолько интегрировались. Pdf они уже открывают внутри себя.

Но с php скрипта запустить печать офис-документа на принтер пользователя... это будет сложно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно реализовать get file content где-то, который будет через GET подбирать нужный файл и выводить на печать.

Comment: Оптимизму у меня конечно прибавилось, но вот реализацию бы увидеть. Сам уже настолько разочаровался, что подумываю о расширении к браузеру, что есть 'беда-печаль..'

Comment: Через неделю буду схожую задачу реализовывать. О результатах сообщу ;)